# Porting Win32 serial (RS232) comms to POSIX

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port, posix, porting

Currently I'm porting a Win32 application to POSIX. The software itself is a couple decades old and used to update proprietary machines.

While most of the functions were relatively easy to replace with simple macros and some smaller functions calling POSIX functions, the RS232 comms-related functions are proving difficult.

The application uses these functions to communicate via RS232:

```
BOOL GetCommState(HANDLE comPort, DCB* dataControlBlock);

BOOL SetCommState(HANDLE comPort, DCB* dataControlBlock);

BOOL GetCommTimeouts(HANDLE comPort, LPCOMMTIMEOUTS comTimeouts);

BOOL SetCommTimeouts(HANDLE comPort, LPCOMMTIMEOUTS comTimeouts);

BOOL SetCommMask(HANDLE comPort, DWORD eventMask);

BOOL GetCommMask(HANDLE comPort, LPDWORD eventMask);

BOOL WaitCommEvent(HANDLE comPort, LPDWORD eventMask, LPOVERLAPPED overlapped);
```

Along with the following structs:

```
typedef struct _DCB { /*...*/ } DCB, *LPDCB;

typedef struct _COMMTIMEOUTS { /*...*/ } COMMTIMEOUTS, *LPCOMMTIMEOUTS;
```

---

While searching, I came across [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519421) link, which mentions termios.h and sys/select.h but the structure of these headers is far too different for my liking. Other answers mentioned using Wine, which simply isn't an option because of the hardware the application is being ported to.

If possible, I'd like to implement a simpler solution and preserve the structs currently being used by the application - in an attempt to keep everything cross-compatible.

Is there a way to achieve this? 
Or am I stuck with re-writing gross portions of the application?

Comment: RS232 in linux is already implemented in the file system. What are you going to archive?

Comment: I'm hoping to use the structure already provided in the application, so I don't have to re-write too much of the application.
Essentially, I need to use RS232 to send (raw) data to a proprierary ECU to update its firmware. The hardware originally used to run the software is no longer being manufactured, so we/I need to port it to different hardware.

Comment: Consider using `boost::asio`. It works for both Windows and Linux. But before you start, check if you can build `boost` for your target machine. In general it is possible - we run `boost` even on `ARMv5` processors.

Comment: `RS232 to send (raw) data to a proprierary ECU` and whar it the problem?

Comment: @P__J__ The problem is, that the application was written for Win32. The question at hand, is whether there is a way to keep the Win32 structure on POSIX machines, so the application can stay next to untouched. Essentially if there's an easy way to create an interface between the Win32 and POSIX syscalls. I've checked out GtkTerm, but that doesn't help much, either.

Comment: @grapes Sadly I'm limited to C for this port, so Boost isn't an option. If there's no other way, then I'll consider making the change. I've only used Boost without compiling it for the current hardware, but it shouldn't be an issue to compile it.

Comment: It is so easy. Judging by the functions names (Wait....) everything is in the synchronous  mode. termio (for the timeouts) is a good direction. probably it will be less than 100 lines in total.

Comment: @P__J__ Mind adding that as an answer with maybe a few lines of exemplary code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how complicated your application is, I see two possible solutions:

1. Replace the Win32 calls with the equivalent POSIX call, as P__J__ mentioned in the comments.  If you do that, the equivalent calls would probably be along the lines of the following:

`GetCommState` : `tcgetattr`

`SetCommState` : `tcsetattr`

`Get/SetCommTimeouts` : You would still set this using `tcsetattr`, modify the `c_cc[VTIME]` entry in of a `struct termios`

`Set/GetCommMask` : Unfortunately, the POSIX API does not have an equivalent of this function.  If you need to care about the control signals(CTS,DSR,RING), you need to read the line status in a loop.  If you only care about reading bytes that come back, you don't need to worry about this.

`WaitCommEvent` : The equivalent on POSIX would be either `select`(old style) or `poll`(more modern).  Similar to the CommMask as above though, `select/poll` will return when there is data to be read, not when the control lines change.

2. If you don't want to try and figure out the cross-platform problems on your own, there are several libraries(in C) that are cross-platform capable.  Here's a quick list:

   - [CSerial](https://github.com/rm5248/CSerial) (note: this is my library, so I'm biased towards it)
   - [libserialport](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport)

..and that's it for everything that I know of.  All of the other libraries that I am aware of are for C++.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out those libraries first and see if I can re-write the application accordingly. Sadly, it is quite a complex application.